# Word/phrase for proving something stronger

Tags: soft-question, terminology, article-writing

I remember encountering a (probably Latin) word/phrase which is used when you prove something stronger than what was desired, and therefore our desired claim follows. I like to collect mots justes, and so I would appreciate anyone helping me remember this one.

As an example: suppose for two finite sets $A$ and $B$, you want to show that $|A| \le |B|$. One way to do that would be to show $A \subseteq B$, from which $|A| \le |B|$ follows. Now we have proved something stronger in order to show our inequality, and in order to finish our proof we ended with a remark saying "from which $|A| \le |B|$ follows" and I want to say instead "[unknown word here] $|A| \le |B|$".

Comment: Try [a fortiori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_a_fortiori).

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was trying to remember.

Comment: קל וחומר in Hebrew

Comment: ["Erst recht"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_a_fortiori) in German.